# how do get value of returned data without extra stuff inlcuded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

An api is sending back data in this format x[[seconds:cost[[x i'm using php and javascript, how do I retrieve the seconds only, than retrieve the cost only

so for example they would send back something like this

```
x[[16413:2.60[[x
```

how can i get the values of seconds/cost without all that extra x[[ stuff included?

i want just the seconds

than i want just the cost

Comment: you could explode the string by : with php how do you get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expression to parse the string.

In JavaScript:

```
var s = 'x[[16413:2.60[[x';

var parts = s.match(/([.0-9]+):([.0-9]+)/);
var seconds = parts[1];
var cost = parts[2];
alert(seconds);
alert(cost);
```

In PHP:

```
$s = 'x[[16413:2.60[[x';

preg_match('/([.0-9]+):([.0-9]+)/', $s, $parts);
$seconds = $parts[1];
$cost = $parts[2];
echo $seconds . "; " . $cost;
```